# Why does GNU Diff not understand UTF-16 (only UTF-8)?

Tags: unicode, diff, utf-16, git-diff, byte-order-mark

Why doesn't GNU Diff understand UTF-16 (only UTF-8)?

This GNU Diff is used by default in Git.

Why doesn't this bug get fixed?

BOM is part of the Unicode standard. http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom4

Why is BOM ignored by most programmers?

In Windows, the encoding of UTF-16 is used by default for some source files.

Comment: The use of BOM and UTF-16 are generally discouraged (I only use BOM on files that have to run on older programs that only understand UTF-8 with a BOM), but as a workaround, you can pipe the files through `iconv` to convert.

Comment: Also, a context diff shouldn't be thrown off by a BOM.  It's just one difference at the start of the file.

Comment: Because no one uses UTF-16 for storing text in files. If you do this, you have a bug and you should fix it - use UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: Powershell - UTF-16

Comment: Powershell, Windows Notepad, Visual Studio - UTF-16. Why should the conversion be in UTF-8?

Comment: @Ivan: "*Because no one uses UTF-16 for storing text in files.*" That's simply not true. I wish it were, but it isn't.

Comment: @Keepun Don't know about Powershell, but others don't use UTF-16. UTF-16 has too many problems and is unsuitable for such task. You are looking for a bug to fix, you should just start using UTF-8.

Comment: Another issue: the spec says you're supposed to store any UTF-16 data as big-endian, but a lot of Windows programs use UTF-16le instead.

Comment: Could try a binary diff?

Comment: If you can (and supporting older tools is the main reason not to) I would recommend standardizing on UTF-8. The rest of the world is dropping the BOM, but if you use or omit it consistently, it will not be a difference.

Comment: POSIX (so in general Unix and similar) does no support UTF16 and similar encoding (API is designed around C strings). So often utilities do no support it (but they could). Unix likes simple things, so one encoding for pathnames, stdin, stdout, etc. `diff` is used also with pipes. One could implement it, but than with UTF16, there are some limitation on how to use `diff`. The "sandwich" principle is valid also there. Convert as early as possible to common encoding. do all operations, and convert back. All will be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-diffutils/2018-04/msg00009.html

> UTF-8 does not require BOM, but for UTF-16 and UTF-32 BOM is always present. Files with UTF-16 and UTF-32 without the BOM should be identified as binary.
>
> But why there are no plans to support UTF-16 and UTF-32? Diff is part of the Git and is used all over the world. Now 2018 and Unicode solved problems with encodings.

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-diffutils/2018-04/msg00011.html

> > why there are no plans to support UTF-16 and UTF-32?
>
> **Nobody has volunteered to do it**, and there hasn't been a pressing need. UTF-16 and UTF-32 are primarily used for internal representation, not for text files. For more on the subject, please see:
>
> http://utf8everywhere.org/

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the GNU diffutils documentation, section 18.1.1 "Handling Multibyte and Varying-Width Characters":

> `diff`, `diff3` and `sdiff` treat each line of input as a string of unibyte
>   characters. This can mishandle multibyte characters in some cases. For
>   example, when asked to ignore spaces, `diff` does not properly ignore a
>   multibyte space character.
>
> Also, `diff` currently assumes that each byte is one column wide, and
>   this assumption is incorrect in some locales, e.g., locales that use
>   UTF-8 encoding. This causes problems with the `-y` or `--side-by-side`
>   option of `diff`.
>
> These problems need to be fixed without unduly affecting the
>   performance of the utilities in unibyte environments.
>
> The IBM GNU/Linux Technology Center Internationalization Team has
>   proposed [patches to support internationalized `diff`](http://oss.software.ibm.com/developer/opensource/linux/patches/i18n/diffutils-2.7.2-i18n-0.1.patch.gz). Unfortunately,
>   these patches are incomplete and are to an older version of `diff`, so
>   more work needs to be done in this area.

It doesn't entirely handle UTF-8 correctly, so it's not surprising that it doesn't handle UTF-16.

(You might be able to alleviate the problem using a locale that recognizes UTF-16. I don't have such a locale on any of the systems I use, including Cygwin under Windows 10.)

A problem I've seen is that a BOM is not recognized as text. You can partially work around that by using the `-a` option, which forces `diff` to assume that its input files are text. When I use this with two little-endian UTF-16 text files with BOM and Windows-style line endings, I get:

```
$ diff hello.txt hello2.txt
Binary files hello.txt and hello2.txt differ
$ diff -a hello.txt hello2.txt 
1c1
< ��hello
---
> ��Hello
$
```

The output is a mixture of UTF-8/ASCII, UTF-16, and garbage.

(I suspect that the underlying reason is that UTF-16 is fairly specific to Windows, and the maintainers of GNU diffutils don't care much about Windows.)

BOM is ignored by most programmers because it's not necessary for UTF-8.